how to modify phtml file without override
Generally, in Magento 2, .phtml files have $block->getChildHtml(), allowing us to put extra data in the .phtml by adding a child to the layout.
If some .phtml file don't have such code and we want to put our custom HTML in a specific area, is there an approach to do that?
Because overriding the .phtml file in the module will require frequent updates when the original .phtml file is updated.
I am seeking a way to add $block->getChildHtml('custom_block_name') in the .phtml before it renders.
Is there any way to do that?
(For example, I need to add block phtml under the customer name on the registration page.)

The only way to do that would be to render the element in a hidden container and then move it to the desired place by using javascript. Why are you not allowed to override the phtml file?

Please try using a layout update file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="product_view">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="Your_Module::product/view.phtml" />
    </update>
</page>

Thank You!

One solution is adding the rendering of your block in the toHtml() class that renders the original block:
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View {

   public function toHtml() {

    $output = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Cms\Block\Block::class)->setBlockId('blog-engagement')->toHtml();
    $output .= parent::toHtml();
    return $output;
   }

}

Remember to setup the preference for this class inside your module to make it work.

It will not place content in a specific place.

You can change the CMS block for whatever you are going to add into the original getChildHtml() call. This prepends your code (by a block or a hardcoded string) before the contents of the parent's gets added. Do you need to add your content in a specific section of the template?
